# Basic orient select / traverse

Tags: orientdb, orientdb3.0

I have a scenario where:

`[Vertex|Class = Company] <-- [Edge|Class = Test1 {'a':'b'}] -- [Vertex|Class = Test2 {'c':'de'}]`

I know the CompanyID so I would like to return in a query Test1.a and Test2.c (in multiples) attached to the Company.

This should be simple enough but I have hit an absolute wall. I've tried:

```
SELECT inE(Test1).a,inV(Test2).c FROM Company WHERE CompanyID = 123
SELECT a,c FROM (TRAVERSE both() FROM #27:16)` (@rid of Company 123)
SELECT bothE(Test1),both(Test2).c FROM Company WHERE CompanyID = 123
```

Option 3 here returns results grouped and I need them expanded per line. Can someone please explain why my queries arent working.

The closest I've come is `SELECT a,c FROM (TRAVERSE bothV(),bothE() FROM #27:16) WHERE @class = 'Test1' OR @class = 'Test2'` however this return a/c results on different lines!

So as per @Ironluca suggestion - yes I can manipulate MATCH to do what I need however is there not a way this can be done with SELECT directly instead? Seems a bit Neo4j for my liking.

Comment: I am not sure this will work as I have not tried it. MATCH {class: Company, where:(id=some_id)}.inE('Test1'){as: t1Edg}.outV(){as: t2Vtx} RETURN t1Edg.a, t2Vtx.c Give it a shot and check if this works or at least gives some meaningful errors :) Based on OrientDB MATCH query https://orientdb.com/docs/last/sql/SQL-Match.html

Comment: I appreciate your direction! Seems to be a little too neo4j for my liking when they want you to be able to use SQL !

Comment: If you don't want to use OSQL, you could directly use the API, the API is available in many languages, e.g in Java you could get a ODatabaseSession and execute an initial SELECT query and then get the vertex, from there the edge and to the next vertex [https://orientdb.org/docs/3.0.x/java/Java-API.html].